# .Net assembly from static c++ library for linux

Tags: c++, .net, linux, c++-cli

We have a static c++ library for windows and linux. To be able to use these classes and functions in .net and powershell, we have wrapped it with c++-cli. Now we would like to use the library for linux powershell too.

Does anyone know a way to do this? Hints and documentation are welcome.

Comment: I think it would have been better to avoid using c++-cli and wrap library into C interface that can be used from .NET wrapper.

Comment: c++-cli would have the advantage that existing powershell code could be used. If that is not possible, can you give any further information to your suggestion?